# How to set the XML value of serialized class using the XmlElement annotation

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a class written in the following manner:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class MyXMLElement
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string AnAttribute { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string AnotherElementAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

When this is serialized, I want to set its Value, so I get something like the following:

```
<MyXMLElement AnAttribute="something" AnotherElementAttribute="something else">The inner value of the element</MyXMLElement>
```

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the value of the element, you can use the `[XmlText]` attribute:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class MyXMLElement
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string AnAttribute { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string AnotherElementAttribute { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another property to hold the inner text and mark it with the XmlTextAttribute

```
[XmlRoot]
public class MyXMLElement
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string AnAttribute { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string AnotherElementAttribute { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string InnerText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Oops, guess I should refresh before posting. =T

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily if you write your own serializer (example below).
This will also give you full control of how your object is persisted rather than relying on how .NET decides to do it.

```
interface IXmlConvertable{
    XElement ToXml();
```

}

```
public class MyClass : IXmlConvertable{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ID { get; set; }

    public XElement ToXml(){

        var retval = new XElement("MyClass"
            , new XAttribute("Name", new XCData(Name))
            , new XAttribute("ID", new XCData(ID))
            );

        return retval;
    }
}
```